# parsley.js extending error message text

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

By design I'm using one div above form to show errors. For this, case I also need some prefix, before each error message, typically it's text from corresponding label tag.

I'd implemented this as extension, just as the new function, which should be executed manually... but in this case I've lost default ui behaviuor.

So, the question is it possible to implement such behaviour as part of parsley (by extending parsley)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd implemented desired behavior by extending two internal functions. Not sure it was good idea, but it does exactly what I needed in some particular cases:

```js
(function ($) {

    function getFieldLabel(parsleyField, suffix) {
        var result = '',
            labels = $('label[for=' + parsleyField.$element.prop('id') + ']');

        suffix = suffix || '';
        if (labels.length) {
            result = labels[0].innerText + suffix;
        }

        return result;
    }

    window.ParsleyExtend = window.ParsleyExtend || {};
    window.ParsleyExtend = $.extend(window.ParsleyExtend, {
        // NB! this method replaces parsley's default `_addError`
        _addError: function _addError(name, _ref5) {
            var message = _ref5.message;
            var assert = _ref5.assert;

            this._insertErrorWrapper();
            this._ui.$errorsWrapper.addClass('filled').append($(this.options.errorTemplate).addClass('parsley-' + name).html(
                getFieldLabel(this, ' - ') + (message || this._getErrorMessage(assert))
            ));
        },

        // NB! this method replaces parsley's default `_updateError`
        _updateError: function _updateError(name, _ref6) {
            var message = _ref6.message;
            var assert = _ref6.assert;

            this._ui.$errorsWrapper.addClass('filled').find('.parsley-' + name).html(
                getFieldLabel(this, ' - ') + (message || this._getErrorMessage(assert))
            );
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize where parsley puts the error with the `errorsContainer`. Could be a function that creates the container within your summary area.

That errors container could also have some sort of other information that you populate.

There is a need for a better error message system, see among others [this issue](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/840).

Comment: Can I achieve this by hacking the plugin rather adding an additional function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but options can be set globally if you want.

Comment: Oh, I see, we talk about different things... How can I extend parsley to show label before each error text? like this
`label1 - field required label2 - value less than % ...` I know I can set error message individually for each element, but I want label + error message as a default plugin behaviour

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this, but answer updated.

Comment: any suggestions how to implement this and preserve ui behaviour?